# AS2Secure drops multipart/signed content-type from headers

Tags: php, content-type, edi

I'm trying to received an AS2 MDN using the PHP lib AS2Secure. The message arrives and decodes just fine, but when the response goes out it strips the main "multipart/signed" value from the `Content-Type`.

For instance, something like this should be in the main header to designate a multipart message:

```
Content-Type: multipart/signed; boundary="----=_Part_8f23d0b4-8a42-4946-9928-4d12d9f7fc66.63"; protocol="application/pkcs7-signature"; micalg=SHA1
```

However, when the response for the multipart message goes out, I only see this in the main headers:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

This triggers an error in the remote server, which expects the message to designate its content-type as multipart.

I tracked the stripping of the multipart content-type down to this code in `AS2MDN.php`:

```
// TODO : replace with futur AS2MimePart to separate content from header
if (strpos($content, "\n\n") !== false) $content = substr($content, strpos($content, "\n\n") + 2);
```

If I remove this code, the missing `Content-Type: multipart/signed` line shows up in the body but `Content-Type: text/html` still shows in the headers.

Any ideas?

Comment: That's the MIME header coming from the partner system, correct? Can they change it?

Comment: The MIME header from the partner system is `multipart/signed` and they expect a similar `multipart/signed` response back. However, the response they are getting from our system for the multipart message is instead `text/html`. It is like something is overwriting the content-type mime values upon output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by the PHP Laravel framework (which handles the app's routing) overwriting headers during output.

Changing this code in the `handle()` method in `AS2server.php`:

```
ob_end_clean();
// send headers
foreach ($mdn->getHeaders() as $key => $value) {
    $header = str_replace(["\r", "\n", "\r\n"], '', $key . ': ' . $value);
    header($header);
}

// output MDN
echo $mdn->getContent();
```

...to this Laravel friendly code:

```
$headers = [];

foreach ($mdn->getHeaders() as $key => $value) {
    $headers[str_replace(["\r", "\n", "\r\n"], '', $key)] = str_replace(["\r", "\n", "\r\n"], '', $value);
}

return \Response::make($mdn->getContent(), 200, $headers); // Use native Laravel response.
```

...solved the problem!